# PYSDM missing in Ubuntu 12.10 and higher

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, pysdm

I have had to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10. I am trying to install PYSDM but it is missing from the repositories.  I have searched for a repo, none to be found... not sure where else to ask because I really do not want to go backwards to have to edit config files, this seems so counter-intuitive.

*Could anyone please direct me on how to install this GUI front end for `fstab`?*

Comment: Relevant Q&A [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/237114/88802). It explains why it has been removed and why not to use it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good just found a solution on Ubuntu 13.04 (salamander):

1) Open the application: Disks.

2) Click on the partition you want to mount automatically.

3) Below is a settings button with two gears, please click and select mounting actions.

4) Double click the folder that is mounted conventionally and fixed where it is mounted. It's usually `media/username/`

...and you're done.

Comment: Would you consider adding an English translation to your answer?

Answer (score 8):

I can't find a GUI, but I found this:

Auto Mounting HDD's

1. You must have all your partitions mounted.
2. Go to the Dash and open a Terminal.
3. Enter the following command:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/mtab
   ```
4. A file will open in Gedit. Scroll to the bottom of the file and your newly mounted devices should be listed.

   For example:

   I looked for `/dev/sda3` & `/dev/sda4` and found them in these lines:

   ```
   /dev/sda3 /media/my_name/Ext\040Storage\0401 ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper+udisks2 0 0
   /dev/sda4 /media/my_name/Ext\040Storage\0402 ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper+udisks2 0 0
   ```
5. Make a note of these lines.
6. Open a new Terminal window.
7. Enter this command:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
8. A file will open in Gedit called `fstab`. This is the config file for the auto mount.

   Now scroll to the bottom of the `fstab` file, copy the lines that you noted and paste them there, save and exit.
9. Now, you have your partitions mounted permanently.

To check everything is mounted without problem, open new Terminal window and enter this command:

```
sudo mount -a
```

If it shows no error, all is working..

Pysdm was a GUI for the above, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any answers available... So if anyone else is in the same predicament I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ir a la web del proyecto y descargarte la aplicación, la puedes instalar con el administrador de software que trae ubuntu 13.10 por ejemplo.

**Translation:**

You must go to the project's website and download the application, the administrator can install software that brings ubuntu 13.10 for example.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/pysdm

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/all/pysdm/download

Answer (score 0):

It's now built-in in Ubuntu from version 13.10: use `Disks` (`Applications -> System Tools -> Preferences -> Disks`).
Click on the partition, then click on the button with two gears, click on `Edit Mount Options`, check the `Mount at startup`, and click `OK`.

There ya go. Easy peasy.